# Is there any way to launch dialogs from a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dialog

It is quite common to find bash scripts showing GUI dialogs using tools such as "dialog".

[image]

I would like to write a MS Windows batch file which could interact with the user through some kind of GUI elements like an input box with some buttons. What is the easier/faster way to do that?

Comment: NOTE: I am looking for a native solution. No Cygwin or other external toolchains should be used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367265/gui-using-batch

Comment: Your native requirement - is that because you don't want to have to install anything on *your* PC, or on the *users*? There are free and open source ways to do this that produce a simple .exe with no other runtime needs and can be distrubuted as easily as the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer depends on what you consider "a native solution". The Batch file below use Cscript.exe external command included in all modern Windows versions, so I think it qualifies as "native solution". However, it really is a hybrid script that include a JScript part that get parameters from the Batch part, activate a Popup GUI dialog box, and return the result to the Batch code as errorlevel.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Popup.bat: Example of use of Popup JScript method
rem Antonio Perez Ayala
rem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx

rem Include auxiliary values for Popup JScript method
call Popup.inc

rem Call Popup JScript method with a 7 second timeout.
set /A buttons=YesNoandCancel + QuestionMark
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "Question:" "Do you feel alright?" /B:%buttons% /T:7
set btn=%errorlevel%
if %btn% equ %YesButton% (
   rem Yes button pressed.
   echo Glad to hear you feel alright.
) else if %btn% equ %NoButton% (
   rem No button pressed.
   echo Hope you're feeling better soon.
) else if %btn% equ %TimedOut% (
   rem Timed out.
   echo Is there anybody out there?
)

goto :EOF

End of Batch section


@end


// JScript section

// Displays text in a pop-up message box.
// CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" ["Title" ["Text"]] [/B:ButtonsType] 

[/T:SecondsToWait]
// set ButtonClicked=%errorlevel%

var title = "", text = "", buttons = 0, seconds = 0;
var args = WScript.Arguments;
if ( args.Unnamed.Length >= 1 ) title = args.Unnamed.Item(0);
if ( args.Unnamed.Length >= 2 ) text = args.Unnamed.Item(1);
if ( args.Named.Exists("B") ) {
   buttons = parseInt(args.Named.Item("B"));
}
if ( args.Named.Exists("T") ) {
   seconds = parseInt(args.Named.Item("T"));
}
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Quit(WshShell.Popup(text,seconds,title,buttons));
```

Popup JScript method show a popup message box that requires an user reply. This method use certain numeric values in ButtonsType parameter and buttonClicked return value; you may define auxiliary variables that contain these values by calling its companion Popup.inc.bat file:

```
rem Popup.inc.bat: Define auxiliary variables for Popup JScript method
rem Antonio Perez Ayala


rem Button Types

set i=0
for %%a in (OK  OKandCancel     AbortRetryandIgnore
                YesNoandCancel  YesandNo
                RetryandCancel  CancelTryAgainandContinue) do (
   set %%a=!i!
   set /A i+=1
)

rem Icon Types

set i=16
for %%a in (StopMark  QuestionMark  ExclamationMark  InformationMark) do (
   set %%a=!i!
   set /A i+=16
)

rem Default Button

set i=256
for %%a in (DefaultButton2  DefaultButton3) do (
   set %%a=!i!
   set /A i+=256
)

rem Button Clicked

set TimedOut=-1
set i=1
for %%a in ( OKButton   CancelButton  AbortButton     RetryButton   IgnoreButton
             YesButton  NoButton _ _  TryAgainButton  ContinueButton ) do (
   set %%a=!i!
   set /A i+=1
)

set _=
set i=


rem Popup.inc.bat: End of file
```

A Jscript program may use other types of Win-32 dialog boxes via DynamicWrapperX: 
http://www.script-coding.com/dynwrapx_eng.html

Comment: That is precisely my point! This solution is comprised of just one file with .BAT extension and use an external command (Cscript.exe) that have a wider distribution than other Batch commands (like Choice or Forfiles, that are not included in Win XP). From this point of view, it is a "native Batch solution". Of course, I must agree that is not a "pure Batch solution". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with David that there is nothing in batch itself, there is a solution that is entirely native and requires only a batch file to work (no install/non native tools) It requires write access to the file system were it's run.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET WINDOWTITLE="Enter Ip Address"
SET QUESTION="Answer the question being asked"
SET DETAIL="Description"
SET DEFAULTANSWER="10.45.76.156"

REM name the vbs file the same as this batch file except .vbs
set FILENAME=%~n0
REM echo the vbs
   echo MSG = InputBox(%QUESTION% ^& VBCRLF ^& VBCRLF ^& VBCRLF ^& %DETAIL%, %WINDOWTITLE%, %DEFAULTANSWER%) >> "%~dp0\%FILENAME%.vbs"
   echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("%~dp0\answer.txt",2,True).Write MSG >>  "%~dp0\%FILENAME%.vbs"
cscript  "%~dp0\%FILENAME%.vbs"
del "%~dp0\%FILENAME%.vbs"

SET /P answer=<"%~dp0\answer.txt"

del "%~dp0\answer.txt"

echo you typed "%answer%"
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Windows batch that will allow you to build a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable to have the GUI interface pop up in a new window rather than being constrained to the command prompt window itself, take a look at HTML Applications (HTA)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

It is standard Windows tech, uses the IE engine to render HTML in a browser-like window (sans toolbars) and provide all the GUI Goodness you could want.

Nice introduction here - "Extreme Makeover: Wrap Your Scripts Up in a GUI Interface"
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use **WinBatch**, but like @David Heffernan said there is nothing with native Batch, you can't (Welcome to Batch).

http://www.winbatch.com/quickstart.html